# Searching in json array

Tags: c#

```json
{
   "medic":[
      {
         "ace":[
            {
               "name":"lisinopril",
               "strength":"10 mg Tab",
               "dose":"1 tab",
               "route":"PO",
               "sig":"daily",
               "pillCount":"#90",
               "refills":"Refill 3"
            }
         ],
         "anti":[
            {
               "name":"nitroglycerin",
               "strength":"0.4 mg Sublingual Tab",
               "dose":"1 tab",
               "route":"SL",
               "sig":"q15min PRN",
               "pillCount":"#30",
               "refills":"Refill 1"
            }
         ],
         "anticoag":[
            {
               "name":"warfarin sodium",
               "strength":"3 mg Tab",
               "dose":"1 tab",
               "route":"PO",
               "sig":"daily",
               "pillCount":"#90",
               "refills":"Refill 3"
            }
         ],
         
      }
   ]
}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ""reporttype"":""post"",
        string jsonString = @"..."; //The above json
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Medication name in which you want to Find STRENGTH value :");
        string medicname = Console.ReadLine();
      
        var rootInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonString);
        }
}
```

```
var result = rootInstance.medications[0].Where(x=>x.name == medicname ).Select(t => t.strength).ToList();
```

But when i run the above query, I get this below error:

> 'Medication' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'Medication' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have added all necessary namespaces to my code.

and Here is my object class

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<Medication> medications { get; set; }
}

public class Medication
{
    public List<aceInhibitors> aceinhibitors { get ; set ; }
    public List<anti> antianginal {get; set; }
    public List<anticoag> anticoagulants {get; set; }
}

public class aceInhibitors
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("strength")]
    public string strength { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dose")]
    public string dose { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("route")]
    public string route { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("sig")]
    public string sig { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pillCount")]
    public string pillCount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("refills")]
    public string refills { get; set; }
}

public class anti
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string strength { get; set; }
    public string dose { get; set; }
    public string route { get; set; }
    public string sig { get; set; }
    public string pillCount { get; set; }
    public string refills { get; set; }
}

public class anticoag
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string strength { get; set; }
    public string dose { get; set; }
    public string route { get; set; }
    public string sig { get; set; }
    public string pillCount { get; set; }
    public string refills { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `Enumerable.Where/Queryable.Where` are  extension methods which are taking `IEnumerable<T>/IQueryable<T>` as first parameter ... does `Medication` implements any of them?

Comment: It's not clear what you are searching for here, the `Medication` object has lots of sublists that have items with the `name` property.

Comment: Your `Medication` type is not a collection, nor does it implement a `Where` method. `x` in your code is of type `Medication`, which of the properties on that object would you like to search in?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Medication` object itself is not searchable. Instead it holds a bunch of list and each contains a different type (where all properties are the same). So maybe you should use some base class for the medicine and add another property to your `Medication` class. In that case you would have a class layout something like this:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public List<Medication> medications { get; set; }
}

public class Medication
{
    public List<aceInhibitors> aceinhibitors { get; set; }
    public List<antianginal> antianginal { get; set; }
    public List<anticoagulants> anticoagulants { get; set; }
    public List<betaBlocker> betablocker { get; set; }
    public List<diuretic> diuretic { get; set; }
    public List<Mineral> mineral { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Medicine> Medicines => Enumerable.Empty<Medicine>()
                                                .Concat(aceinhibitors)
                                                .Concat(antianginal)
                                                .Concat(anticoagulants)
                                                .Concat(betablocker)
                                                .Concat(diuretic)
                                                .Concat(mineral);
}

public class Medicine
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("strength")]
    public string strength { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dose")]
    public string dose { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("route")]
    public string route { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("sig")]
    public string sig { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("pillCount")]
    public string pillCount { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("refills")]
    public string refills { get; set; }
}

public class aceInhibitors : Medicine
{
}

public class antianginal : Medicine
{
}

public class anticoagulants : Medicine
{
}

public class betaBlocker : Medicine
{
}

public class diuretic : Medicine
{
}

public class Mineral : Medicine
{
}
```

And prepared with that you could now ask something like that:

```
var result = rootInstance.medications[0].Medicines
    .Where(x => x.name == medicname)
    .Select(t => t.strength)
    .ToList();
```

If the model of the classes really matches your desires is up to you, but it should give you starting point.

If you want it *more inline* you could also do something like this:

```
public class Medication : IEnumerable<Medicine>
{
    public List<aceInhibitors> aceinhibitors { get; set; }
    public List<antianginal> antianginal { get; set; }
    public List<anticoagulants> anticoagulants { get; set; }
    public List<betaBlocker> betablocker { get; set; }
    public List<diuretic> diuretic { get; set; }
    public List<Mineral> mineral { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<Medicine> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<Medicine>()
            .Concat(aceinhibitors)
            .Concat(antianginal)
            .Concat(anticoagulants)
            .Concat(betablocker)
            .Concat(diuretic)
            .Concat(mineral)
            .GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
```

And in that case you could write something like this:

```
var result = rootInstance.medications[0]
    .Where(x => x.name == medicname)
    .Select(t => t.strength)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your domain model is bit suboptimal as it was pointed out by Oliver. If you need to stick to this model, then you can do the following.

1. Introduce an interface for fields that are interesting from your query point of view:

```
public interface InterestingFields
{
    string name { get; }
    string strength { get; }
}
```

Each medication class can be easily adjusted to implement it, like:

```
public class Mineral: InterestingFields
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string strength { get; set; }
    public string dose { get; set; }
    public string route { get; set; }
    public string sig { get; set; }
    public string pillCount { get; set; }
    public string refills { get; set; }
}
```

2. Make the properties of the `Medication` class queryable

```
var properties = typeof(Medication).GetProperties()
        .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType
        && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>)
        && typeof(InterestingFields).IsAssignableFrom(prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0]))
        .ToList();
```

I've used reflection where the property's type is a `List<T>` and `T` is assignable to `InterestingFields`

3. Go through the properties, retrieve the actual value and do the filtering based on that

```
var medication = rootInstance.medications[0];

var result = from property in properties
        let collection = property.GetValue(medication) as IEnumerable<InterestingFields>
        let element = collection?.ToArray().First()
        where element?.name == medicname
        select element.strength;

Console.WriteLine(result.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper design would lead to a separation from the data handling and the way that your data is stored. This way, it is easy to reuse the stored data for other handling, it is easier to unit test the data handling with test code, you can change the way that the data is stored, to for instance a CSV file, or XML, without having to change the data handling code.

So you need a class `Medication`:

```
class Medication
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Strength {get; set;}
    public string Dose {get; set;}
    ... // etc.
}
```

Consider to change Dose and Strength to a numerical value.

Apparently you have stored all Medications somewhere. A proper software design would hide where it is stored, and what format it is stored in. All you know is, that you can store Medications in it, and fetch it back later, even after your program is restarted. Such a storage is often called a `Repository`:

```
class MedicationRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Medication> ReadMedications() {...}
}
```

The actual implementation is up to you. I think you'll use [Nuget Package NewtonSoft Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) for this. Maybe you also want methods to Add / Change / Remove Medications?

Consider to let the Repository class implement `IEnumerable<Medication>`, or even `ICollection<Medication>`, depending on what is most efficient in your case.

```
class MedicationRepository : IEnumerable<Medication>
{
    public IEnumerator<Medication> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.ReadMedications().GetEnumerator();
    }

    ...
}
```

Now that you've got a method to read all Medications, we can get back to your LINQ problem:

> I need get input string from user(which is medication name in json) i need to check if input matches the name in medication and need to display corresponding strength value.

So you've got a procedure to read the medication name:

```
public string ReadMedicationName() {...}
```

And you want the Strength of all Medications with this name.

```
MedicationRepository medications = ...
string requestedMedicationName = this.ReadMedicationName();

string medicationStrength = medications
    .Where(medication => medication.Name == requestedMedicationName)
    .Select(medication => medication.Strength)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In words: from all Medications, keep only those Medications that have a name that equals requestedMedicationName. If the name is unique, then there will be zero or one Medication left. From all remaining Medications, take only the value of property Strength, and take the first strength, or null if there is no Medication with this Name at all.

Can it be that there are several Medications with this name? Which one do you want in that case, just any Strength (= .FirstOrDefault()), all Strengths (= ToList())? In the latter case: how do you distinguish which Medication with this name contains which Strength? Consider to `Select` more properties in that case.

### Conclusion

By separating the storage of the data and how you get the requested Medication Name from the data handling, it is easier to change the storage (to XML, to CSV, to a database), and it is easier to unit test the LINQ using specific test data.

Similarly: you've hidden how you get the name of the requested Medication: is it a DOS prompt? Did you read it from a file? Maybe you've changed it to a WinForms application and you read it from a Textbox, or a ComboBox. Because you separated, the LINQ doesn't have to change, and can be reused in several platforms.